# different sets of git branches

Tags: git, terminal, iterm2

I've found myself in a strange situation with git.

I have a different set of branches listed when I run `git branch` depending on the terminal window I am in, even when I am in the same project folder.

My "current" terminal window shows something like:

```
recent_branch_1
recent_branch_2
recent_branch_3
master
```

Where as any NEW terminal tab (after browsing to my project folder) results in:

```
old_branch_1
old_branch_2
old_branch_3
master
```

Any help on how to figure out where these are coming from and how to either combine them all, or just keep the more recent set of branches would be appreciated!

Comment: What does the command `pwd` print in both tabs?

Comment: oh my goodness!  looks like one version was in the same folder path but under a dropbox folder.....if you want to answer the question I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad it helps. Let's just leave it as a comment.